# Redirect User to Homepage if no other redirect is specified

Tags: users, redirect, login

Basically I want to write some code that decided wether to redirect a User to the Home page of the website or to the page that the user came from prior to logging in.

I have this code which successfully redirects users to the page they came from if a redirect back to that page has been specified. However, if there is no specific redirect request, users are sent to the backend admin panel.

```
<?php
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {

    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {

        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {

            if($request){
                $redirect_to = $request;
            } else {
                $redirect_to =  home_url();
            }

        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

How can I tweak this so that the users don't get to see the admin panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so let's take a deeper look, how this hook is used in WP... It's fired up in [`wp-login.php` (on line 901):](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-login.php#L901)

```
$requested_redirect_to = isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : '';
// ...
$redirect_to = apply_filters( 'login_redirect', $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user );
```

So, the variable you called `$request` (which is a little bit misleading, it should be called `$requested_redirect_to`) should be empty, so your code should work just fine. But... There's always a but ;)

If you'll got o `wp-login.php` and take a closer look at login form, then you'll see, that there is a hidden input called `redirect_to` in it and it contains URL of `wp-admin`. So this condition `if($request){` is always true.

You can fix it this way:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
    if ( isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles) ) {

        if ( in_array('subscriber', $user->roles) ) {

            if ( $requested_redirect_to && admin_url() != $requested_redirect_to ) {
                $redirect_to = $requested_redirect_to;
            } else {
                $redirect_to =  home_url();
            }

        }
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```